# Low performance CUDA code on GT540M

Tags: c, performance, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Executing the following code sample takes ~750 ms on a GeForce GT540M whereas the same code executes in ~250 ms on a GT330M.

Copying the dev_a and dev_b to the CUDA device memory takes ~350 ms on the GT540M and ~250. The execution of "addCuda" and the copying back to the host takes another ~400 ms on GT540M and ~0 ms for the GT330M.

This is not what I expected, so I checked the devices' properties and discovered that the GT540M device surpasses or equals GT330M in every way except in the number of multiprocessors - GT540M has 2 and GT330M has 6. Can this really be true? And if so, can it really have such a great impact on the execution time?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define T 512
#define N 60000*T

__global__ void addCuda(double *a, double *b, double *c) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid < N) {
        c[tid] = sqrt(fabs(a[tid] * b[tid] / 12.34567)) * cos(a[tid]);
    }
}

int main() {
    double *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    double* a = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* b = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* c = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));

    printf("Filling arrays (CPU)...\n\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = (double)-i;
        b[i] = (double)i;
    }

    int timer = clock();
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_a, N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_b, N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_c, N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printf("Memcpy time: %d\n", clock() - timer);
    addCuda<<<(N+T-1)/T,T>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Time elapsed: %d\n", clock() - timer);

cudaFree(dev_a);
cudaFree(dev_b);
cudaFree(dev_c);
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);

return 0;
}
```

The device properties for the devices:

**GT540M:**

```
Major revision number:         2
Minor revision number:         1
Name:                          GeForce GT 540M
Total global memory:           1073741824
Total shared memory per block: 49152
Total registers per block:     32768
Warp size:                     32
Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
Maximum threads per block:     1024
Maximum dimension 0 of block:  1024
Maximum dimension 1 of block:  1024
Maximum dimension 2 of block:  64
Maximum dimension 0 of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension 1 of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension 2 of grid:   65535
Clock rate:                    1344000
Total constant memory:         65536
Texture alignment:             512
Concurrent copy and execution: Yes
Number of multiprocessors:     2
Kernel execution timeout:      Yes
```

**GT330M**

```
Major revision number:         1
Minor revision number:         2
Name:                          GeForce GT 330M
Total global memory:           268435456
Total shared memory per block: 16384
Total registers per block:     16384
Warp size:                     32
Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
Maximum threads per block:     512
Maximum dimension 0 of block:  512
Maximum dimension 1 of block:  512
Maximum dimension 2 of block:  64
Maximum dimension 0 of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension 1 of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension 2 of grid:   1
Clock rate:                    1100000
Total constant memory:         65536
Texture alignment:             256
Concurrent copy and execution: Yes
Number of multiprocessors:     6
Kernel execution timeout:      Yes
```

Comment: The first point to make is that the GT330M doesn't support double precision, so you are comparing a single precision result on one device with a double precision one on the other. There is an 8x performance performance difference between the two on current hardware. Can you also add what operating system and CUDA version each is running on to your question, these are mobile parts so they clearly are not running in the same host machine.

Comment: In general I think you need to benchmark much larger jobs on CUDA to outweigh the setup / tear-down time. It's surprising the older card can do that more efficiently, though, but is this really a factor in your real application?

Comment: Machine 1:
GT540M (Computing capability 2.1)
CUDA version 4.1
Intel Core i5-2410M
Windows 7 64bit.

Machine 2:
GT330M (Computing capability 1.2)
CUDA version 4.1
Intel Core i5-520M
Windows 7 64bit on bootcamp for Mac.


Computing a similar add function on the CPU takes ~2500 ms (on both machines). I tried to replace all doubles with floats to see if it changed anything, but it did not. Does the GPU still use double precision even though it is not required by the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it isn't possible for a copy from device to host to be ~0ms. I would suggest to check if there is stg wrong with that copy

Comment: The copy from host to device went wrong somehow, and the function I used to check the results was faulty.. It seems that the GT540M is indeed faster as would be expected from the specs.

Answer (score -3):

Look at the number of multiprocessors.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't explain anything. One has 6 MP with 8 cores which can only retire a single precision FMAD for a warp every 4 clock cycles. The other has 2 MP with *48 cores* each which can retire a single precision FMAD for *two warps* every 2 clock cycles, plus it has a 20% higher clock rate. Both can perform limited instruction level parallelism, in the GT300M case it is only a potential single precision multiply, in the GT540M it can be a single precision FMAD.